# Cannot convert unknown characters format to latin utf-8

Tags: xcode, rsync

After running rsync 3.0.7, the result (using -v) is wrongly formatted, the result contains strange characters ("é" is replaced by "#314#201").
I have try to convert the result to utf latin characters using "iconv" but it failed. Maybe because I don't know what is the source encoding format (of the result of rsync).
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this helps: [rsync FAQ](https://rsync.samba.org/FAQ.html), in the section *rsync recopies the same files*

Comment: It is interesting but does not work for me (I am using Mac OS)                  sudo /usr/local/bin/rsync -nprogvIX --size-only --iconv=UTF-8,UTF8-MAC report an error :                                                                                              rsync: --iconv=UTF-8,UTF8-MAC: unknown option
rsync error: syntax or usage error (code 1) at main.c(1425) [client=3.0.7]

Comment: I have to precise that I am not speaking about the files copied ( the copied files have the right characters, the same as the source ones), but I am speaking about the result of the verbose option of rsync (with is wrongly formatted).

Comment: I was just a thought. Maybe you could *iconv* the result with the `UTF8-MAC` option.

Comment: This is what I have try to do (using --iconv on result) but nothing happened, the result is the same as the source, probably because I don't know the starting format. I have try different combinaisons but they are too many to try them all. It would be easier if I could know what is the format of the result.

Comment: Let's make it clear. If I try to use --iconv with rsync, I get the 'unknown option' error. If I try to convert the log file (resulting of an execution of rsync) by using iconv, the output is the same as the input.

Comment: There is this flag of rsync "--log-file-format=FORMATNAME" which does not ask for input format and which seems to be made for this purpose but again, the output is wrongly formatted, like the flag is not taken into account. I tried quite a few format (UTF8-MAC, UTF-16BE, UTF-16LE, LATIN1, CSISOLATIN2).

Comment: Here it is, for all the Latin lovers! I added the -8 flag and it worked! Nothing else needed.

Comment: Exemple : /usr/local/bin/rsync -naiXv8 --size-only /SourcePath/ /DestPath/

Comment: It is the second time that I find myself an answer to a tricky question and it only happens on this site. Is it due to the general enthusiasm of the people here? Or to the quality of the answers? I guess both played a great role. Thank U all!

Comment: The "v" flag shown in the exemple is useless.